# Is it possible to typeset left and right angle brackets?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting

I would like to typeset the following in a *Mathematica* notebook:

$$\langle P \rangle$$

Is it possible to typeset left and right angle brackets?  In $\LaTeX$, they are given by `\langle` and `\rangle`.  I do not see such symbols in the documentation, but I may be overlooking them.

Comment: It's in the Writing Assistant - Typesetting palette. You can also use `AngleBracket[...]`, or type `esc` < `esc`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the listing of all named characters](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html)

```
 \[LeftAngleBracket]P\[RightAngleBracket]
```

Answer (score 13):

Mathematica provides angle-bracket symbols `\[LeftAngleBracket]` and `\[RightAngleBracket]`, which act like other brackets.

You can easily input them using "<kbd>Esc</kbd> `<` <kbd>Esc</kbd>" and "<kbd>Esc</kbd> `>` <kbd>Esc</kbd>".

Mathematica will also parse $\langle a, b, c, ...,z\rangle$ as `AngleBracket[a, b, ..., z]`, which is useful if you're generating a typeset expression.

For [the particular usage of angle brackets in quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra-ket_notation), there are also the convenient input aliases "<kbd>Esc</kbd> `bra` <kbd>Esc</kbd>", "<kbd>Esc</kbd> `ket` <kbd>Esc</kbd>", and "<kbd>Esc</kbd> `braket` <kbd>Esc</kbd>" for [image: Mathematica graphics], [image: Mathematica graphics], and [image: Mathematica graphics] respectively.

Answer (score 8):

In the form of an operator:

```
AngleBracket[P]
```

outputs as $\langle P \rangle$, which, under the hood, is just:

```
\[LeftAngleBracket]P\[RightAngleBracket]
```

See also: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/Operators.html